# Hibernate Template Session query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

We are using Spring HibernateTemplate class for hibernate operation. I need to execute a query with in clause and setting the options for in using an arrayList. For that i need a org.hibernate.Query object.

```
String queryStr = "from CertMetadataCfg where metadataId in (:metadataIds)";
Query query=hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery(queryStr)
query.setParameterList("metadataIds", metadataSet);
```

but for retrieving Query object we have to open a new session. Why do we need to open a session. and when should we close this session .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HibernateTemplate does the opening and closing of the session handling.

Please check the documentation.

Use findByNamedParam -

```
getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam("from CertMetadataCfg where metadataId in (:metadataIds)", "metadataIds", metadataIds);
```

Comment: when i tried this approach.i am getting this error. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!

Comment: getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam("from CertMetadataCfg where metadataId in (:metadataIds)", "metadataIds", metadataIds);        metadataIds should be a list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do only a read, you dont need to open the session. Use `getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString);`